# Add button to ngx-cookie-consent (cookie personalization)

Tags: angular, cookies

I'm using ngx cookie consent to ask user if he agrees with cookie storage and usage.

link : https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent

So I try this module that is perfect BUT has no option for cookie personalization pop-up.

I'd like to have three buttons : Decline, Accept AND Personalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to implement your own cookie layout? As far as i see its possible to inject a totally custom html part by yourself via config:

```
const cookieConfig:NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost'// it is recommended to set your domain, for cookies to work properly
  },
  palette: {
    popup: {
      background: '#000'
    },
    button: {
      background: '#f1d600'
    }
  },
  theme: 'edgeless',
  type: 'opt-out',
  layout: 'my-custom-layout',
  layouts: {
    "my-custom-layout": '{{buttons}}'
  },
  elements:{
    buttons: `
    <span id="cookieconsent:desc" class="cc-message">{{message}} 
     <button (click)="delclineCookies()">Decline</button>
     <button (click)="customomizeCookies()">Customize Cookies</button>
     <button (click)="acceptCookies()">Accept</button>
    </span>
    `,
  },
  content:{
    message: 'By using our site, you acknowledge that you have read and understand our '
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you sickpig ! It is what I needed. And this implementation worked :)

Comment: can you please tell me where I have to write that customizeCookies function?